# Testing Crontab on Debian Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, debian, cron

I will preface this by saying I am very new to command line programming with Debian Ubuntu...

I have been trying to set up a crontab list on a Debian Ubuntu server but have not been able to  get it to work. Here is a sample:

```
MAILTO=myemail@gmail.com
* * * * * wall test
* * * * * /usr/bin/python2.6 /home/user/test.py > /home/user/clean_tmp_dir.log
```

The above shows up when I type "crontab -l" but no resulting output appears in the console. The "test.py" is supposed to generate a csv file but none is being created.

I am not receiving any output/error emails. I tried to find a log, but "var/log/cron" does not exist, nor does "etc/syslog.conf"...I tried to edit "etc/rsyslog.conf", but got "E212: Can't open file for writing"...I am logged in, however. Do I need some sort of special administrative privileges? Do I need to specify user or "root" or something?

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong, how I can create/view a log, or how I can perform any other straightforward tests? Thanks!

Comment: Log entries for `cron` should be in `/var/log/syslog` (at least they are on my Ubuntu system).  I tried copying your crontab to my system (updating the MAILTO) and got an error message for the `wall` command: `wall: will not read test - use stdin.`  I can't guess about `test.py`, but is `clean_tmp_dir.log` created?

Comment: When I try "tail syslog", I get "tail: cannot open 'syslog' for reading: Permission denied" -- do you know why this is? i created clean_tmp_dir.log manually. I also wonder why I'm not getting any emails...

Comment: On my system, `/var/log/syslog` has permissions 640 (read-write for owner, read-only for group), owner "syslog", group "adm".  I can read it because I'm a member of the "adm" group.  Either use `sudo tail /var/log/syslog` or add yourself to the `adm` group.  The `clean_temp_dir.log` file should be created by the cron job; if it isn't, the cron job probably isn't running.  Is the cron daemon running (`ps -f -u root | grep cron`)?  Does your system have `/etc/cron.allow` and/or `/etc/cron.deny`?  `man crontab` for more information.

Comment: I'm currently waiting on getting ahold of the root password so I can add myself to the sudoers file. When I type "ps -f -u root | grep cron" I get the following:
root       715     1  0 Apr28 ?        00:00:09 cron
There are no cron.allow or cron.deny files on my system.

Comment: You said you created clean_tmp_dir.log manually.  Try deleting it.  With the crontab file you showed us, it should be created within a minute.  If it is, you know your cron jobs are being executed; if not, there's a problem with cron (and you should talk to your sysadmin).

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the troubleshooting help! I talked to the sysadmin and got permission to view the logs. It turned out the environment was not set up properly (and likely issues with the wall test command as well). There are also issues with the mail setup that he is currently trying to fix. I am now able to see error messages after putting my commands in a shell script and redirecting stderr/stdout to a log

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Ok, let's start over again.

Create a file, say `cron.txt`, with exactly the following contents (1 line):

```
* * * * * touch $HOME/CRON_IS_RUNNING
```

(Do *not* create CRON_IS_RUNNING manually.)  Run

```
crontab cron.txt
```

which should quietly produce no output, then

```
crontab -l
```

which should print

```
* * * * * touch $HOME/CRON_IS_RUNNING
```

Wait a minute or so, perhaps 2 minutes, then

```
ls -l $HOME/CRON_IS_RUNNING
```

which should print something like

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 yourname yourgroup 0 2011-08-23 20:11 CRON_IS_RUNNING
```

If this all works, it will confirm that you can run cron jobs.

If that's successful, the problem may be with your `test.py` command.  Does it work when you run it from the command line?  If it works from the command line but not from `cron`, `test.py` might have some dependency on environment variables (cron jobs run with fewer environment variables set than interactive commands typically do).

Answer (score 1):

The syntax in your wall command is wrong.  To output a direct message you need to use the syntax:  `echo test | wall` .   `wall test` will look for a file named test.

Any cron messages will be in `/var/log/syslog`

Your cronjob will be located in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/username` which is owned by

username:crontab

I ran a test on my system "Debian Squeeze" with your crontab slightly modified as the root user.

I created a file test.py with:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "hello"
```

created the wall file test with:

```
this is a test
```

Then ran crontab -e and added this to my crontab:

```
MAILTO=myemail@gmail.com
* * * * * wall /usr/local/src/test
* * * * * /usr/bin/python2.6 /usr/local/src/test.py > /usr/local/src/test.log
```

When it ran this was output to the screen:

```
Broadcast Message from root@X-Wing                                             
        (somewhere) at 21:09 ...                                               

This is a test
```

The contents of test.log contained:

```
hello
```

This was added to /var/log/syslog:

```
Aug 23 21:08:49 x-wing crontab[9850]: (root) REPLACE (root)
Aug 23 21:08:49 x-wing crontab[9850]: (root) END EDIT (root)
Aug 23 21:09:01 x-wing /usr/sbin/cron[1615]: (root) RELOAD (crontabs/root)
Aug 23 21:09:02 x-wing /USR/SBIN/CRON[9860]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/python2.6 /usr/local/src/test.py > /usr/local/src/test.log)
Aug 23 21:09:02 x-wing /USR/SBIN/CRON[9862]: (root) CMD (wall /usr/local/src/test)
```

Comment: With an argument, `wall` reads from the named file (in this case, it will look for a file named "test").  Without an argument, it will read from stdin.  Adding a control-D to the command line doesn't make any sense; it would cause `wall` to look for a file named `test<ctrl-D>`.  If the intended message is "test", the syntax is `echo test | wall`.

Comment: Oh, and if the file "test" doesn't exist, `wall test` will die with an error message: `wall: will not read test - use stdin.`.  If cron is working properly, that message should be e-mailed to the owner of the crontab.

Comment: I've never heard of the `<ctrl-d>` syntax before.  Maybe I'm misinterpreting the [Debian Wall man page.](http://www.debianadmin.com/manpages/wallmanpage.htm)

Comment: Sorry, I just meant that it will look for a file whose name consists of the 5 characters "test" followed by a control-D character (as a C string literal, `"test\004"`).  Typing control-D when reading input *interactively* will cause an end-of-file condition.  That doesn't apply in a non-interactive context like a cron job or a shell script.  If you want the `wall` command to print the string "test" in a non-interactive context, you have to arrange the wall process's stdin to consist of the single line `"test"`.  The way to do that is `echo test | wall`.

Comment: Note that the Debian man page you referenced says "When using the standard input *from a terminal*, ..."; that doesn't apply here.

Comment: Thanks for the correction.  I edited the answer but the error still should have been emailed.