# cant get a cron job running on debian

Tags: linux, debian, cron

I've got a Debian VPS with a few websites on. I'm currently using django quite heavily.

I want a cron job to run and schedule a script inside one of my django sites. The upshot is that I can't get the Cron job running and I'm not sure how to sort it, as I've not got a lot of Linux experience.

my /etc/crontab file

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
HOME=/home/shofty
LOGNAME=shofty
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO="info@webbricks.co.uk"

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report     /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
#
```

so I've set the job up in "crontab -e"

```
50 10 * * * /home/shofty/virtualenvs/webbricks/bin/chronograph -e /home/shofty/virrtualenvs/webbricks/bin/activate_this.py -p /home/shofty/virtualenvs/webbricks
```

but it doesn't appear to run at the time im trying for (10:50 is arbitrary, I'm adjusting it every few minutes to get it to run after changing a setting or another).

i think cron is running because i can do

```
/etc/init.d/cron stop
```

but the same command with a start fails. obviously witha  start after to make it run again. 
from everything i've read, the output of a ps aux hints that it is running.

```
root@shoftys - server>_ /home/shofty# ps aux | grep cron 
root     19106  0.0  0.0  18548   948 ?        Ss   10:42   0:00 /usr/sbin/cron
root     27130  0.0  0.0   3876   600 pts/0    S+   15:52   0:00 grep cron
```

I've added a > /home/shofty/virtualenvs/webbricks/cron.log to the command in crontab but it doesn't seem to want to output a logfile.
and im getting absolutely nothing in /var/log/cron, it just says its a new file.

as a noob, im a bit unsure where to go next, would someone who knows a lot more about linux, debian and cron suggest where to look next please?

Comment: after quite a bit of checking stuff with sillyMunky, this is down to not having permission to run the job. found it out by trying to run the job manually. not sure why i dont have permissions but think that deserves a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Its all much easier than that!

Revert all your changes to the crontab and instead add a link to your script in /etc/cron.daily or /etc/cron.hourly as required.  How often would you like it to run? If more often or more precise times I can help you out there too.  But if you just want a daily/hourly script to run, put it (or a link to it) in one of those directories.

If you want to control the specific time your script runs, better put it in crontab:
0 1    * * *   username    /path/to/my/script

You were just missing the username! When that happened your cron-tab would have looked wrong and that's why you weren't able to /etc/init.d/cron start again ;)

p.s to add a link into the cron.daily directory:

ln -s /path/to/my/script /etc/cron.daily/scriptname

Comment: much clearer, thanks

i wouldnt mind tieing it down to say 1AM, how would i do that?

Comment: I've edited the answer to include how to fix the method you were using (add in the username field)

Comment: sorry, mis-read you stuff about starting and stopping it.  Btw, /etc/init.d/cron status  will tell you if its running ;)

You were missing the username in the line you posted (goes in between the time and the command), which can prevent cron running properly.

Comment: safe to assume that cos i've done a SU to be able to edit crontab that i need to use root inside that file?
----

im still unsure as to why i dont get a logfile created at /var/log/cron

Comment: /etc/init.d/cron status doesn't work, could that have something to do with it? tells me Usage: /etc/init.d/cron {start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload}.

Comment: @shofty what?! I've never seen a debian box who's cron doesn't support 'status'! On mine: # /etc/init.d/cron status \
Checking periodic command scheduler...done (running).

You can use `ps ax | grep cron` to check that the process is running

Comment: seriously mate, thats the exact output when i type that command in. i did find this post on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071255/testing-crontab-on-debian-ubuntu and from it i can deduce i can run a cron job to create a file, so pretty sure its running. which means its the format of my job or the script file its calling. i think.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3494/discussion-between-sillymunky-and-shofty)